# How to convince python that an int type is actually a hex type?

Tags: python, hex

I have been given a hex value that is being treated as an int by python. I need to get this value treated as hex without changing the value. I tried using data = hex(int(data, 16)) but this makes my data a string. Is there a way to change an int to a hex without actually changing the representation?

Ex: data = 9663676416, type(data) = int
I want: data = 0x9663676416, type(data) = hex

Comment: The representation is the only thing that *does* change. They're both stored as binary in the backend and converted to decimal or hex when you display them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = int(str(9663676416),16)
print x
print hex(x)
```

as mentioned in the comments what you have is a number .... all you do is mess with the representation ...

if you want `type(x) == hex` you will need to do something else (tbh im not sure what ... you can certainly do stuff like `isinstance(x,hexNumber)`

```
class hexNumber:
   def __init__(self,x):
      if isinstance(x,str):
         self.val = int(x,16)
      elif isinstance(x,int):
         self.val = int(str(x),16)
   def __str__(self):
          return hex(self.val)

y = hexNumber(12345)
print "%s"%y
print isinstance(y,hexNumber)

y = hexNumber("1234abc")
print "%s"%y
print isinstance(y,hexNumber)
```

Comment: Re-read the OP's question. He's trying to get `type(data)` to return "hex" and not "string". This is a confusion about the type system, not how to get Python to show a hex representation of an `int`.

Comment: Thanks! Haha pretty easy in the end!